# How to add index in values with array type column

Tags: scala, apache-spark, parquet

I have a requirement to add sequence number to the columns (Array)
where my source data is in parquet format and volume is nearly 2 Billion records.
where i have to choose only key and code column from parquet and add sequence number to ref_codes and load it to back to S3

```
Key_1       Key_2       Key_3  Ref_codes
112240386   7435038894  2    [4659,53540,78907]
113325994   7940375640  1      [7232,7840,83969]
223352476   7765270324  4      [9999]
345936074   7950076012  1      [78650,4829,30000]
            
            
Key_1       Key_2       Key_3   Ref_codes
112240386   7435038894  2       [(4659,0),(53540,1),(78907,2)]
113325994   7940375640  1       [(7232,0),(7840,1),(83969,2)]
223352476   7765270324  4       [(9999,0)]
345936074   7950076012  1       [(78650,0),(4829,1),(30000,2)]
```

I am new to Scala, I have tried multiple option but doesn't got the proper results.Any help really appreciated...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use higher-order functions like `transform` in the latest versions of spark as below.
Data:

```
val df = Seq(
  ("112240386", "7435038894", 2, Array(4659, 53540, 7890)),
  ("113325994", "7940375640", 1, Array(7232, 7840, 8396)),
  ("223352476", "7765270324", 4, Array(999)),
  ("345936074", "7950076012", 1, Array(78650, 4829, 3000)),
).toDF("key_1", "key_2", "key_3", "ref_code")
```

**Spark 3.0.0+**

```
df.withColumn("ref_code", transform($"ref_code", (x, i) => struct(x, i) ))
```

**Spark > 2.4**

```
df.withColumn("ref_code", expr("transform(ref_code, (x,i) -> (x,i) )"))
```

**Spark < 2.4**

```
val addIndex = udf((arr: Seq[Int]) => arr.zipWithIndex)
df.withColumn("ref_code", addIndex($"ref_code")).show(false)
```

Output:

```
+---------+----------+-----+----------------------------------+
|key_1    |key_2     |key_3|ref_code                          |
+---------+----------+-----+----------------------------------+
|112240386|7435038894|2    |[[4659, 0], [53540, 1], [7890, 2]]|
|113325994|7940375640|1    |[[7232, 0], [7840, 1], [8396, 2]] |
|223352476|7765270324|4    |[[999, 0]]                        |
|345936074|7950076012|1    |[[78650, 0], [4829, 1], [3000, 2]]|
+---------+----------+-----+----------------------------------+
```

More example on transform is [here](https://koiralo.com/2020/06/26/transform-arraytype-maptype-column-in-spark/)

Comment: Hi Koiralo, Its worked fine .. thanks a lot for the solution

Comment: Yes, it worked fine .. I even tried for bigger volume It’s working good.